# Dell Latidute Home Office Workspace

Tags: hub, cable, docking-stations

I just received a Dell Latitude 7210 2-in-1 as workstation from my new employer. Since I'll have to work in home office for the next few weeks or months (due to covid) I'll have to setup an home office workspace.

Now my employer already gave me Dell DisplayLink to connect one of my monitors and ethernet. But I have only one accessible USB slot and now I'm kinda lacking the possibility to connect all of my peripherals.

In fact I am looking for recommondations in regards of USB Hubs or Docks with multiple ports (maybe for also my second monitor).

What I want to connect is the following:

- Wireless Mouse (1 Dongle USB)
- Wired Keyboard (USB)
- Wired Headphone station (USB)
- External SSD (USB)
- HDMI / VGA Monitor
- HDMI / DP Monitor
- If possoble additional pc audio boxes (Minijack)
- Ethernet

What I am able to connect now with the Dell Display Link

- Wireless mouse
- One Monitor via HDMI
- Ethernet

Are there any recommondations on combinations of docks / hubs / cables to achieve my setup?
Also it shouldn't be to pricey if possible.